# GLSL - Opentk pass an array of Vector3's

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

How can i pass an array of Vector3's to a GLSL shader using OpenTK?
In OpenGL for C++ there is a function called glUniform3fv, however i can't seem to find any equivalent for OpenTK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenTK - the "gl" prefix per method is not available (because you have to access all OpenGL methods via the static class GL). The call is, instead

```
    GL.Uniform3(...)
```

Look at line 21318 in the [sources](http://opentk.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opentk/trunk/Source/OpenTK/Graphics/OpenGL/GL.cs?revision=3125&view=markup).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes thankyou very much! I thought the float array parameter was only for passing in 3 floats (same as vector3)